# Consolidate awk expressions

Tags: shell, awk

How can I combine this two expressions into one to be used in an awk script file?

```
awk '/select name="op_sys"/,/select>/' build/input.xhtml > build/output.xhtml
awk '/value="/,/">/' build/output.xhtml
```

**Edit:**
I would like to transform the expressions in an awk file to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be dangerous merging the two range expressions. For example, what if the second range occurs outside of (or partially overlaps) the first range? I would simply use a pipe:

```
< build/input.xhtml awk '/select name="op_sys"/,/select>/' | awk '/value="/,/">/'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` does not permit address ranges to be nested easily.  You can do it with flags, but it's much simpler to use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/pat1/,/pat2/ { /pat3/,/pat4/p }'
```

will print lines between `pat3` and `pat4` (inclusive) only within `pat1` and `pat2`.  Note that nesting ranges like this does not behave exactly as piping the output to a second invocation, since overlaps will be treated differently.